# Keyboard not working on Cordova project

Tags: android, jquery, eclipse, cordova

I have a unknown problem and simply its about keyboard
I created a phonegap project before and everything was fine
but for now , I made another project ( cordova included instead of phonegap.js ) and in all pages when focus on each input ( or textareas ) keyboard does not work and does not enter any text
Just show cursor on input without entering texts or number
Let me know what I should to do ?
Is there any plugin that I had to install on eclipse ?
Thanks

Comment: could you provide the Android API version?

Comment: Yes , I think it is 4.0

Comment: could you show me your code sample?